# Unit test with mocha + chai always passed

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, bdd, chai

I try to use 'mocha' and 'chai' for my unit test but I have a problem with the test result, it always passed.
Please take a look.

**UnitTest.spec.ts**

```
import PostgresService from "../src/Services/PostgresService"
import {expect} from "chai"
import 'mocha'

describe('Postgres Override Test function', () => {
    it('should return any number but not zero', async () => {
        let client = new PostgresService();
        let result = await client.getLatestCMD("Servo");   
        try{
            console.log("Type : " + typeof(result));
            console.log("Value : " + result.rows[0].id);
            expect(result.rows[0].id).to.equal(0)        
        }catch(error){

        }
    })
})
```

[image]

Comment: remove the try catch block

Comment: @LiroyLeshed.com It's work! but why?

Comment: Many unit test framework indicates error by throwing an exception. If you catch an exception silently, you have effectively disabled the signalling mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the try catch block to actually run your `expect` function.

If your `try` block returns an error the JavaScript interpreter moves on to the `catch` block and so the former is never run.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ASYNCHRONOUS CODE`, you need done in the callback

example

You need to declare done as an argument to `it`.

```
it('description', (done) => {
    expect((err, result) => {
    if (err) done(err);
    else done();
 })
})
```

Comment: OP is already using promises and `await`, which is sufficient. `done` isn't really relevant here. The problem is `try`/`catch`.