# Mocha test with SuperTest always passes (even when wrong)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, supertest, mern

I'm using Mocha and SuperTest to test my Express API. However my first test always seems to pass when inside the `.then()` of my `request()`.

I'm passing in a `String` to a test that is expecting an `Array`. So should definitely fail the test.

It fails outside of the `then()` as expected, but I won't have access to the `res.body` there to perform my tests.

Here is my code:

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const request = require('supertest');

const router = require('../../routes/api/playlist.route');
const app = require('../../app');

describe('Playlist Route', function() {
    // before((done) => {

    // }
    describe('Get all playlists by user', function() {
        it('Should error out with "No playlists found" if there are no Playlists', function() {
            request(app).get('/api/playlists/all')
                .then(res => {
                    const { body } = res;

                    // Test passes if expect here
                    expect('sdfb').to.be.an('array'); 
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('err: ', err);
                });
            // Test fails if expect here
            expect('sdfb').to.be.an('array'); 
        })
    })
});
```

I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111489/unit-test-with-mocha-chai-always-passed) but I'm not using a `try catch` block, but I thought maybe it could have something to do with the promise.

Comment: It doesn't *pass*, it just doesn't fail - there's a difference. You have to be careful when testing asynchronous code, because it's very easy to accidentally write assertions that don't get reached until *after* the test is over (TDD is one way to ensure this doesn't happen). For Mocha, see https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll take a look at the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick reponse

```
it('decription', function(done) {
    asyncFunc()
        .then(() => {
            expect(something).to.be(somethingElse)
            done()
        })
})
```

Detailed response in the comment of @jonrsharpe

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this. `done` is less direct than simply returning or awaiting the promise that supertest gives you via `request`. `.catch(err => done(err))` is also needed here. It's more syntax, harder to read and easier to mess up. Once you're in promises, I would forget about `done`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `done`, simply `return request(app).get('/api/playlists/all')` since `request()` returns a promise. Since you have `expect('sdfb').to.be.an('array');` twice, remove the one that's not in the `.then` callback. When using asynchronous code, remember that synchronous code that appears to come after the async chain will execute *before* the promise `.then` handlers. This is counterintuitive.

Here's the `.then` approach:

```js
it('should ...', () => {
  return request(app)
    .get('/api/playlists/all')
    .then(res => {
      const {body} = res;
      // assert here
    });
});
```

The other approach is to `await` the promise yourself in the test case function, then make assertions on the resolved response object. In this case, drop the `then` chain. This approach is generally preferred as it reduces nesting.

```js
it('should ...', async () => {
  const res = await request(app).get('/api/playlists/all');
  const {body} = res;
  // assert here
});
```

If you don't let Mocha know you're working with asynchronous code by returning a promise, `await`ing the promises, or adding and calling the `done` parameter, the assertions occur asynchronously after the test is over and disappear into the void, creating a false positive.

Skip `.catch` either way. Since you've informed Mocha of the promise, if it rejects, it'll let you know.